# Is this the proper way of accessing data members of a class?

Tags: c++, class, implementation

I am using separate compilation for a homework assignment and I had a question about accessing data members of a class I have created. When implementing the member functions of a class that does not take any parameters and I need to access the data member of that class, how would I do this in C++? I know that in Java, there is the `this` keyword which refers to the object that calls on the function.

My header file:

```
#ifndef _POLYNOMIAL_H
#define _POLYNOMIAL_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Polynomial {

    private:
        std::vector<int> polynomial;

    public:
        // Default constructor
        Polynomial();

        // Parameterized constructor
        Polynomial(std::vector<int> poly);

        // Return the degree of of a polynomial.
        int degree();
};
#endif
```

My implementation file:

```
#include "Polynomial.h"

Polynomial::Polynomial() {
        // Some code
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(std::vector<int> poly) {
    // Some code
}

int degree() {
    // How would I access the data members of the object that calls this method?
    // Example: polynomialOne.degree(), How would I access the data members of
    // polynomialOne?
}
```

I was able to directly access the private data member `polynomial`, but I was wondering if this is the correct way to access data members of an object or would I have to use something similar to Java's `this` keyword to access a particular objects data members?

Comment: More than often you're going to use the name of the data member instead of `this->xxx`. If you have a parameter name that happens to be the same name as a data member, the parameter will take precedence, but you can use `this->xxx` to directly refer to the data member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function should be defined as a member of `Polynomial` using the `Polynomial::` prefix.

```
int Polynomial::degree() {
}
```

Then you can access the member variables such as the vector `polynomial`.

Comment: So in C++, it is fine to directly use member variables when implementing it's member functions?

Comment: Yes. In fact, if the member variables are declare `private`, the member functions are the *only* functions that may access those variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope your function definition of degree to your class so the compiler knows that degree belongs to Polynomial. Then you can access your member variables like so:

```
int Polynomial::degree() {
    int value = polynomial[0];
}
```

Without scoping degree to your class two things are happening. Your Polynomial class has a degree() function defined without any definition. And you have degree() function defined in your .cpp file that is a standalone function that is not part of any class, thus you can't access member variables of Polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a "Polynomial::" to the "degree()" function.

You think that the "degree()" function you write is part of the "Polynomial" class, but, the compiler treats it, like an independent, "global" function.

So:

```
int degree() {
    // How would I access the data members of the object that calls this method?
    // Example: polynomialOne.degree(), How would I access the data members of
    // polynomialOne?
}
```

Should be:

```
int Polynomial::degree() {
  int SomeValue = 0;

  // Do something with "this->polynomial;" and "SomeValue"

  return SomeValue;
}
```

Cheers.